# Scale from Center to margin

Tags: modeling, vertices, faces, transform-orientation

new player here.
I have made this model and I want to raise the center to let's say 8 cm and the margin remains like that, 2cm. I want to give it a round semi-sphere shape from the center, along with the designed model.  I tried and kinds of scaling but I can't seem to find the right one. Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks[image]

Comment: Have you tried selecting a vertex in the centre of the disk, turning on Proportional editing with the O key then G Z and move it up? - You may have to reduce the circle of influence with the middle mouse button to get the curve that you want.

Comment: Effin magic man. thanks alot. it does the job

Comment: Good to hear. A useful tool! :^) [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/editors/3dview/controls/proportional_editing.html?utm_source=blender-3.6.5#bpy-types-toolsettings-use-proportional-edit) is the Manual reference about it.